# Alternate solution for https://math.stackexchange.com/q/458071/691870

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $f$ be an entire function with $|f(z)|\le 100\log|z|,\forall |z|\ge 2,f(i)=2i, \text{ Then} f(1)=?$

I am trying to solve this question using Cauchy's Inequality .

Now since given that function is entire therefore it is continuous on circle $|z|=2$ and have a maximum value of $|f(z)|$ in and on that circle , let's call it M that is $ M=max \{ |f(z)| : |z|≤2\}$.

Now for $|z|>2$ we have $$|f(z)|\le 100\log|z|<100|z|$$

Now consider that circle $|z-z_0|=R$ now on circle we have
$$|z|≤|z_0+Re^{i\theta}|≤(|z_0|+R)$$

Thus if we define

$$M' = max\{M, 100(|z_0| +R)\}$$

Then we have $|f(z)|\leq M'$
Following by that $\lim_{R\to \infty} \frac{M'}{R^2}=0$ and Cauchy's Inequality we have

$$|f"(z_0)|\leq0 , \forall  z_0$$

So using antiderivatives we have

> I have doubt in this step ,  Is it right to integrate wrt z directly when f(z) is analytic ? )

$$f(z) = az +b$$ where a and b are complex constants .

> Is this solution right or there is some mistake I made ?

> I can get one relation from given condition , how to get other to eliminate a and b ?

Comment: link https://math.stackexchange.com/q/458071/691870

Comment: Cauchy's estimate gives $|f^{(n)}(0)| \le n! {100 \log R \over R^n}$ for $R \ge 2$. Hence $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for $n \ge 1$ and so $f$ is constant.